# How can change this sql queries to prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Code:

```php
$gameID= $_GET['gid'];
$con = mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpassword);
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sqlselect="SELECT * FROM games WHERE gameid=" . $gameID;
$result = mysql_query($sqlselect);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$gwidth =  $row['width'];
$gheight = $row['height'];

if($gwidth > 700)<br /> {
  $gwidth = $gwidth * 0.75;
  $gheight = $gheight * 0.75;
}
```

can anybody tell me how to secure this sql queries ?

VULNERABILITY: CLASSIC MYSQL INJECTION

Comment: FWIW, "gameID" != "games".

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_escape_string or mysqli_escape_string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: can you give me an example with the code i  attached using mysql_escape_string?

Comment: -1. Not only are you recommending a deprecated extension, you are also recommending a very old and broken function in it. "*This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0.*" "*This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.*"

Comment: I mentioned mysqli_escape_string as well